# Control Comment permissions based on OG Roles

Tags: 7, organic-groups, comments

Using OG 7.x-2.7, we have an OG role called contributor that we'd like to use as the decision point to allow or not to allow content contribution *in that group.*

[image]

Of the Group Content nodes, how do I allow the OG contributor role to comment and at the same time allow other group members to see comments but not add comments themselves?

**What I've tried so far**

*[Commment OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_og)* but I could not get this module to work. I structured the OG permissions as below, but was still about to comment as only a user with the Member role.

[image]

Comment: do you have any Drupal-level comment permissions set?

Comment: Yes. Authenticated members can create nodes. OG permissions allow Members to create certain pieces of content.

Comment: But do they have access to comment?